# Can I run a plumbing vent through a wall instead of the roof?

Tags: pipe, vent

I'm working on a tiny cabin bathroom. I would not like to run a vent pipe and cut an opening in the roof. Are there any other options on the placement of vent for waste?

Answer (score 1):

You will need some kind of vent or the gasses will end up inside the house. In my jurisdiction tiny homes follow very similar rules to standard construction so a minimum of 1 vent will be needed. A second vent could be achieved by using an air admittance valve if allowed in your area.

I wired a mobile home not long ago and the owner had his vent on the trailing wall below the ridge. We passed electrical and I did not notice any plumbing changes so that may be an option. I would verify with your local inspector.

Comment: To clarify, did the vent exit the wall and bend upward, above the roof line?

Comment: Below the ridge line is below the roof at the point the pipe ended outside the wall. I believe this was done for towing but it would be in a down draft area to me I asked when I first saw it and he said that was the recommended location.  No windows or other openings close to it. I have not been back as it was just a T&M job I did not know the owner but was doing the job for a contractor friend I work for on the side.

Comment: I assumed that you meant the pipe penetrated the wall below the ridgeline, not that it terminated there.